# Connecting to MongoDB from Java Throws Error?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to connect to Mongo DB Server from Java code. I am able to connet to the same server from Command line. But When I connect from Java code, I am facing some issues.
Below is the Command Line I am using to connect to the DB :

```
mongo --username user --password pwd --authenticationDatabase authDB --ssl --host xxx.yyy.com --port 37043
```

I am able to connect with the above command Line. I am using the Below Java code to connect to MongoDB :

```
MongoClientOptions.Builder options = MongoClientOptions.builder().sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true);
String url="mongodb://user:pwd@xxx.yyy.com:37043/authDB?ssl=false"
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(url,options));
System.out.println("Opion"+client.getDatabaseNames());
```

I am getting the Below Exception :

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:570)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:441)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:295)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=xxx.yyy.com:37043, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:182)
       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
       at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:136)
       at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:94)
       at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:249)
       at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:172)
       at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:132)
       at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:86)
       at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.forEach(MongoIterableImpl.java:110)
       at com.mongodb.client.internal.MappingIterable.forEach(MappingIterable.java:54)
       at com.mongodb.client.internal.MappingIterable.into(MappingIterable.java:64)
       at com.mongodb.Mongo.getDatabaseNames(Mongo.java:480)
       at it.damore.solr.importexport.MongoConnect.main(MongoConnect.java:25)
```

Note: I tried connecting to the Same server from MongoDB Compass as well. I am able to connect successfully. In MongoDBCompass, I select SSL as `Unvalidated(insecure)` and SSHTunnel as `None`.

Please help if I am missing on something while connecting from Java code.

Comment: You're enabling ssl in the command line, did you already try doing the same in your java code?

Comment: @delephin yes I tried SSL as true .. but I am getting lot more errors in that case like key not present and similar exceptions

Comment: Which driver version are you using?

Comment: Is your MongoDB can be connected without the SSL?